# 2 dimensional sprite sheet moving forward and back to starting point

Tags: javascript, css

I am using CSS to make an animation with a 2-dimensional sprite sheet. I was able to animate it with the animation property. However, it only animates the character in the same spot, so I want to move the character to create a walking animation from point A to point B and the second row shows the character turns and faces the opposite side and start walking. So for the second row of the sprite, I hope to make the character to maintain his current position after translating 400px from the first row and move 400px back to the starting point. Is there a way for CSS to do this or I have to convert the sprite sheet to 1-dimensional in order to do it or I can use Javascript to do it?

```css
div.c {
  background: url("https://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite/img/scottpilgrim_multiple.png");
  width: 108px;
  height: 140px;
  animation: x2 1.5s steps(8) infinite, y2 3s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes x2 {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -864px;
    transform: translatex(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes y2 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -280px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c"></div>
```

So if I do it this way the animation begins and the first 4 frames in the first row works fine, but when it comes to the second row the image teleports back to the 0px starting point and translates 400px and the character facing the opposite direction walks backward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the animation using only CSS.

A CSS keyframe needs to know where to start and where to end. At `0%` is the start, at `100%` is the end of the animation.If you want your animation to 'loop' you need to fit the half of the animation inside the first half of the keyframe and the rest of it inside the other half. Also, you have to take in account the sprite's width when calculating the distance you want to travel.

```css
div.c {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: black;
  background: url("https://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite/img/scottpilgrim_multiple.png");
  width: 108px;
  height: 140px;
  animation: x2 1.5s steps(8) infinite, y2 3s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes x2 {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-x: -864px;
    transform: translatex(508px);
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes y2 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -280px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c"></div>
```